# if/else statement selects in between two for loops

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I am a novice and trying to write the After Effects script where I will like that checkbox selection selects in between two different loops. IS this possible? Below is the setup of the script I have. I would like "frRowCheck" checkbox 0 and 1 to trigger certain for loop.

```
var comp = app.project.activeItem;
   var layGrid = comp.selectedLayers[0];
    
    var effA= layGrid.property("Effects").property("Grid").property(1); // anchor
    var effW= layGrid.property("Effects").property("Grid").property(4); // width
    var effH= layGrid.property("Effects").property("Grid").property(5); // height

   var laySelectIndex = layGrid.property("Effects").property("Layer Source For Grid").property("Layer").value; //number  of selection 
   var laySelect = comp.layer(laySelectIndex); // layer selected based on the index
   var selectR = laySelect.property("Effects").property("ROWS").property("Slider").value; // number of rows
   var selectC = laySelect.property("Effects").property("COLUMNS").property("Slider").value; // // number of columns
   var frRowCheck = laySelect.property("Effects").property("Enable First ROW Control").property("Checkbox").value; //check on/off

    var numbHorG = selectR*2+1;  // number of needed horizontal guides based on the number fo rows
    var numbVerG = selectC*2+1;  // number of needed horizontal guides based on the number fo columns

    var numbHorGMin = (selectR-1)*2+1;  // number of needed horizontal guides based on the number fo rows if 1st row enabled
    var numbVerGMin = (selectC-1)*2+1;  // number of needed horizontal guides based on the number fo columns if 1st row enabled

   var effX = effA.value[0]; // value of X anchor
   var effY = effA.value[1]; // value of Y anchor
   var effHor = effW.value;  // value of Width
   var effVer = effH.value;  // value of Height

    

    if(frRowCheck == 0) {
          ;
    } else {
          ;
     }            // I know this is not right but I would like this


    for(i=0; i<numbHorG; i ++) {
        comp.addGuide(1, effX + i*effHor);
    }

    for(i=0; i<numbVerG; i ++) {
        comp.addGuide(0, effY + i*effVer);
    }


    for(i=0; i<3; i ++) {
        comp.addGuide(1, effX + i*effHor);
    }

    for(i=0; i<3; i ++) {
        comp.addGuide(0, effY + i*effVer);
    }
```

Comment: you can write different functions having the loops as per your requirements and then call the function inside from the if else block . This may solve your probelm

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that I can name or make for loop something like a variable so I can use it in if/else statement?
Does that work for example

var z = for(i=0; i<numbHorG; i ++) {
        comp.addGuide(1, effX + i*effHor);

Comment: This is some kind of Adobe ExtendScript version of Java Script but let's say JavaScript. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you don't put the `for` loops inside the appropriate part of the `if else`? e.g. `if (something){ for (var i = 0; i < foo; i++){dostuff()} } else { for (var i = 0; i < bar; i++){doOtherStuff()} }`

Answer (score 0):

try this (If I understand you correctly)

```js
if(frRowCheck == 0) {
  for(i=0; i<numbHorG; i ++) {
    comp.addGuide(1, effX + i*effHor);
    comp.addGuide(0, effY + i*effVer);
  }
} else {
  for(i=0; i<3; i ++) {
    comp.addGuide(1, effX + i*effHor);
    comp.addGuide(0, effY + i*effVer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).